# Flutter Scrollable Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My Column won't scroll when using this piece of code:

```
Flexible(
   child: new ListView(
   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   children: <Widget>[
       CarsList(uid: widget.uid),
       MotorbikeList(uid: widget.uid)
     ],
   )
),
```

[image: I can open both Expansion Tiles just fine and also other expansion tiles within them, but I can't scroll down to see the ones hiding in the bottom.]

[image]

When I wrap them individually into Flex Widget I can then scroll through them but they are not using the entire space of the column when expanded.

```
Flexible(
   child: CarsList(uid: widget.uid),
),

Flexible(
   child: MotorbikeList(uid: widget.uid),
)
```

[[image: Now I can scroll down, but they don't expand as I want them too[3]]

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
  Flexible(
    child: new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  CarsList(uid: widget.uid),
                  MotorbikeList(uid: widget.uid)
                  },
                childCount: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ])),
      ],
    ));
```

Comment: There is a height constraint problem with this one. I'm trying some workarounds, but so far no success :/
Thanks a lot for the suggestion tho. Really appreciated :)

Comment: Really thanks you solved my issue. I can't believe it was that easy <3

Comment: Thumbs Up dear, Thank you so much, Flexible with ListView worked like charm :)